# Count top 5 persons that were most together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a check-in table that consists of the flowing columns:

```
PK CheckInID int
PersonID int
CheckInDate smalldatetime
```

I'm trying to create a query that gives me a top 3 of persons who most frequently were checked-in together for a specific person.

For example:

```
personID 1 was 
18 times together with personID 3
13 times together with personID 9
11 times together with personID 4
```

Implementing this in C# is not really a problem for me but I want to create a stored procedure and TSQL is not really my strong side.

Comment: Please post sample data. Your descritpion is unclear.

Comment: If two check-in occurs with 1 seconds difference in time both are not counted as together, ie like 10:15:29 will be rounded to 10:15:00, and 10:15:30 will be rounded to 10:16. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/smalldatetime-transact-sql Values that are 29.998 seconds or less are rounded down to the nearest minute, Values of 29.999 seconds or more are rounded up to the nearest minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that date is designator:

```
SELECT TOP 3 PersonId, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM your_table
WHERE CheckInDate IN (SELECT CheckInDate 
                      FROM your_table     
                      WHERE PersonId = ?)  
  AND PersonId <> ?  -- do not count the same person
GROUP BY PersonId
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster way (no subquery and no "IN" statement) is :

```
SELECT TOP 3 T2.PersonId
   , SUM(1) AS NB_TIME_CHECKED_IN_WITH_XXX
FROM your_table AS T1
   INNER JOIN your_table AS T2 ON (T1.[PK CheckInID]=T2.[PK CheckInID] AND T2.PersonId <> XXX)
WHERE T1.PersonId = XXX
GROUP BY PersonId
ORDER BY NB_TIME_CHECKED_IN_WITH_XXX DESC;
```

Comment: No subquery and completely wrong. `WHERE PersonId = XXX` and in conditional sum you have `SUM(CASE WHEN PersonId<>XXX THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: Still I would say that they should have very similiar execution plans.

Comment: I've never seen a 8623 or 8632 error caused by a huge number of argument for an IN statement... Still I would say that execution time can be higher depending on the number and the weight of argument list returned by the subquery. With my query, an index on PersonId and [PK CheckInID] is required.